Is it possible to perform database IO asyncrhonously (async IO) using SQLX in Rust?
I am seeing pretty poor performance with some code which moves data from one datastore to a SQL database.
Currently I manage to process about 200 messages / second.
I initially wrote this utility in Python. I then re-wrote it in Rust. Initially, I thought that part of the reason for the poor performance was due to Python. (The code does a bunch of other potentially expensive calculations which might have been significantly faster in a compiled language such as Rust, rather than Python which has overhead when working with Python objects. It turns out this was not the bottleneck.)
It is a bit tricky to give a useful MWE for this. Let me present something, then the nuances can be discussed later.
use sqlx;
use chrono;
use futures;

fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {

    println!("connecting to Postgres...");

    let pool =
        futures::executor::block_on(
            sqlx::postgres::PgPoolOptions::new()
            .max_connections(5)
            .connect("postgresql://postgres:password@192.168.0.x/postgres")
        ).expect("failed to connect to Postgres");

    println!("connected to Postgres");

    
    let html_data = "<div>some long string read from file, ideally a few kb in size</div>";

    let datetime_start = chrono::offset::Utc::now();

    // insert html_data row
    let query_result =
            sqlx::query(
                "insert into html_data (html_data) values ($1)"
            )
            .bind(html_data)
            .fetch_optional(&pool);

    let _optional_row = futures::executor::block_on(query_result).expect("block_on failed");

    let datetime_stop = chrono::offset::Utc::now();
    let duration = datetime_stop - datetime_start;
    let duration = 1.0e+3 * duration.num_seconds() as f64 + 1.0e-9 * duration.subsec_nanos() as f64;
    println!("insert html_data: {duration} ms");
    
    Ok(())
}

What this code does is simple:

It establishes a connection to a Postgres database
It inserts a row into a table
The table has two columns, the primary key id column and html_data, which is of type varchar
The database operations are all synchronous. futures::executor::block_on is used to convert an asynchronous interface into a synchronous one

The round-trip time appears to be in the region of 10 ms, which explains the message processing rate of 100 messages / sec.
Fortunatly, many of the database calls could be made asynchronous. Sometimes I have a branch statement which depends on some data returned by the database, but in many cases I just insert data as this example shows.
To convert this code into something which uses asynchrnous io, my current understanding is that I can do the following:

Instead of blocking on the completition of the future returned by sqlx::query ... .fetch_optional(), I could do something else with that future and block on it later.

The problem is, I don't know what I should do with it.
The type of query_result is
impl Future<Output = Result<<Postgres as Database>::QueryResult, Error>>

Perhaps I misunderstand, but I don't think creating query_result causes it do to anything.
If I understand correctly, calling executor::block_on on query_result will

start the function running
this will send a network request to the database
it will then wait for the database to respond
finally, the future will have been completed and any return values are returned
executor::block_on finishes

What I actually want is something more like this:

start the function running
send network request to database
do not wait for a response, return some kind of future which I can block on at a later time

However I am not sure if such a thing is possible.
Basically, my idea is it would be nice to have something like a "fire and forget" request. (Except rather than totally forgetting about it, we can check it completed later.)

Instead of using async functions in sync context, use them in the asynchronous one. If you don't mind introducing extra dependencies, then just add this to Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.0", features = [ "rt-multi-thread", "macros" ]}

this will allow you to use async code in tokio runtime (or you can explore others depending on your needs, like monoio or glomio)
then you can use the sqlx in following fashion:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    println!("connecting to Postgres...");

    let pool = sqlx::postgres::PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(5)
        .connect("postgresql://postgres:password@192.168.0.x/postgres")
        .await
        .expect("failed to connect to Postgres");

    println!("connected to Postgres");

    let html_data = "<div>some long string read from file, ideally a few kb in size</div>";

    let datetime_start = chrono::offset::Utc::now();

    // insert html_data row
    // this is a handle to asynchronous task running on tokio runtime
    let pl = pool.clone();
    // spawn the query task on the async runtime
    // this is basically fire and optionally forget apprach
    let query_handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        sqlx::query("insert into html_data (html_data) values ($1)")
            .bind(html_data)
            .fetch_optional(&pl)
            .await
    });
    // save the handle if you want to check the results later
    // let mut queries = futures::stream::FuturesUnordered::new();
    // queries.push_back(query_handle);

    // you can await on the result of query immediately or at a later time
    // you can spawn million queries without awaiting them immediately, and
    // use something like `FuturesUnordered` to keep the handles around and check the results at
    // your convenience
    let result = query_handle.await;
    // process the result
    //match result {
    //    // ..
    //}

    let datetime_stop = chrono::offset::Utc::now();
    let duration = datetime_stop - datetime_start;
    let duration = 1.0e+3 * duration.num_seconds() as f64 + 1.0e-9 * duration.subsec_nanos() as f64;
    println!("insert html_data: {duration} ms");

    Ok(())
}

This should be something similar to what you have described with fire and forget approach.

I'm not particularly familiar with tokio vs async-std. Is it neccessary to change the async framework to do this? I'm not against changing it, just more curious to understand why you chose tokio instead of async-std in this case?

No it's not necessary, but by using async code the way you do, by calling block_on on each Future, you are essentially negating all the benefits of asynchronous execution by turning your code into linear and synchronous.
Spawning Futures onto the runtime like tokio allows them to run concurrently and with multithreaded runtimes even truly parallel.

To clarify my question, is there an alternative to tokio::spawn as part of the async-std framework? I'm trying to understand if your suggestion of using tokio is an essential part of the solution or whether you just happened to have a personal preference for tokio over async-std. I don't know what the differences between them are, so I cannot form an opinion on which one to use, at least not right now.

tokio is just the most popular async runtime in Rust ecosystem with a lot of sowtware being written around it, you can keep using futures crate, it has an executor module which allow you to spawn things, but it's kind of awkward to use and not as performant as tokio

you can use any available async runtime out there, they all have very similar API, tokio, async-std, monoio, glomio, you can even write your own simple executor.

Right I see. I will probably have to dig into the history a bit. It seems odd that the framework maintained as part of the standard library isn't the "go to default". (Unless it just has a badly chosen name and it's nothing to do with standard library?)

Maybe a slightly different question actually - is there a way to trigger fetch_optional to start running but return early rather than wait for data to come back from PG? Then I really could write my own runtime - or a cut down version of one. Which might bethe most appropriate solution.

async-std is not part of standard library, it's not officially affiliated with rust foundation, and in fact it's slowly being phased out

spawning Future on runtime (any runtime) starts running it immediately and returns the handle also immediately, in the true spirit of asynchronous execution. The returned handle can be used to check the status of task later, for example when there's nothing else to do. Using FuturesUnordered allows you to keep all those handles around and return those which already completed when you poll it.

Does a runtime have to be a new thread? (Different to the current one.) I guess I will have to figure out exactly what defines a runtime. Just trying to forsee if a "runtime" could be the current thread, which perhaps could know when to yield the task. (In this case when waiting for network IO.) Maybe what I am asking for would require modifying the postgres SQLX library itself, which is probably not a road I want to go down. Spawning a thread, for it to just "do almost nothing" (wait for some network io) seems like it might be inefficient due to the overhead of launching a thread.

depends on the runtime, it can run on the same thread, different thread, or a thread pool. In the example above with a tokio, it runs on a thread pool (with N threads, where N is number of logical CPU cores available). But in general you have to read about the runtime you want use to understand its execution model.

also I'd recommend to read about rust async model itself, it's a bit different from other languages. Runtime is a just piece of synchronous software, and so if you run it on some thread, you cannot run anything else on that thread, just like you cannot run two sync loops simultaneously on the same thread. But async tasks which run "inside" the runtime can and do run concurrently and yield the control back to runtime when they cannot make any more progress.
